# Как на modx сделать отправку заявок через formIt

Tags: html, modx, formit

Есть сайт, которую перенесли с Wordpress на ModX. После чего форма отправки заявок перестала работать. Как можно завершить процесс создания формы через FormIt на ModX. Пока создала чанк для этой формы и вызвала этот же чанк на самой странице, а дальше по инструкции не понятно. Подскажите пожалуйста как завершить процесс создания формы.
код чанка

```
 <form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" class="wpcf7-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input_inside">
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap name_1"><input aria-invalid="false"
    aria-required="true"
    class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required data_input"
    name="name_1"
    placeholder="ВАШЕ ИМЯ"
    size="40"
    type="text"
    value="[[+fi.name_1]]"
    id="nm1" required /></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input_inside">
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email_1"><input aria-invalid="false"
    aria-required="true"
    class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email data_input"
    name="email_1"
    placeholder="ВАШ EMAIL"
    size="40"
    type="email"
    value="[[+fi.email_1]]"
    id="em1" required/></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input_inside">
                <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit ddddddddd" type="submit" value="ПОДПИСАТЬСЯ" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

А на самой странице

```
<div id="sub_news">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="input_inside_title oyt">
                                <h2>Подписка на новости</h2>
                                <p>Подпишитесь на новости и будьте в курсе наших событий</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="textwidget">
                            <div class="wpcf7" dir="ltr" id="wpcf7-f2551-o1" lang="ru-RU" role="form">
                                <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
                                [[$form1-tpl]]
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Из `<form action="[[~[[*id]]]]"` следует, что вы передадите данные формы после отправки на эту же страницу. А кто их обработает? Нужен вызов Formit, у вас его не вижу.
Посмотреть примеры вызова можно здесь: [Formit пример простой формы](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.tutorials-and-examples/formit.examples.simple-contact-page)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]